# How to prevent insert when condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a two tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ID int not null,
    Status int not null,
    TimeStamp datetime2(3)

    CONSTRAINT pkId PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Status (
    StatusID int not null,
    StatusName varchar(64) not null
    
    CONSTRAINT pStatus PRIMARY KEY (StatusID)

);
```

with inserted values

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,StatusID,TimeStamp) VALUES 
(1,1,'2021-06-15 07:30:31'),
(2,2,'2021-07-15 07:30:31'),
(3,3,'2021-08-15 07:30:31'),
(4,4,'2021-09-15 08:30:31'),
(5,5,'2021-09-15 07:30:31'),
(6,5,'2021-09-15 07:30:31'),
(7,4,'2021-09-15 07:30:31'),
(8,2,'2021-09-15 07:30:31'),
(9,1,'2021-09-15 07:30:31');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Status (StatusID,StatusName) VALUES
(1,'wants to enroll'),
(2,'granted enrollment'),
(3,'declined enrollment'),
(4,'attending the course'),
(5,'finished the course');
```

I wrote a trigger but it prevent all insert when the StatusID < 4 and what I want is to prevent insert into TimeStamp only when the condition is StatusID < 4. I use SQL Server.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Prevent_Insert4
ON dbo.table1
FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * 
           FROM dbo.table1 t 
           JOIN inserted i ON t.ID=i.ID 
           WHERE t.StatusID<4)
BEGIN
        RAISERROR('You can not update when StatusId value < 4', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as " insert into TimeStamp". Insert is about row. To deal with columns you use UPDATE

Comment: I recommend against using `ROLLBACK` in a `TRIGGER`; it causes an additional error. You would be better off `THROW`ing an error with an appropriate state and then the outer transaction can handle the rollback.

Comment: You surely realise your error message states you cannot *update* in a trigger that only handles *inserts*...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a `CHECK` constraint

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Status
    CHECK(Status >= 4 OR TimeStamp IS NULL);
```

---

If you *really, really* wanted to use triggers for this (not recommended) then it should look like this

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Prevent_Insert4
ON dbo.table1
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF  EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.StatusID < 4
      AND i.TimeStamp IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, 'You can not set TimeStamp when StatusId value < 4', 1;
    -- no need for rollback, will happen automatically if you use THROW
END;

go
```

Comment: I have to use trigger

Comment: Why do you *have* to? You should use the most suitable tool for the problem, and a trigger is not that.

Comment: because the task requires it

Comment: Well I've added the solution for that also

Comment: than you for your help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

With your code you are doing rollback of inserted row when condition is met. If I understood you correctly you just to want override timestamp with null value if StatusId < 4.

If so, you should write that instead of rollback

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.table1 t 
    JOIN inserted i ON t.ID=i.ID 
    WHERE t.StatusID<4)
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET t.TimeStamp = NULL 
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN dbo.table1 t ON i.ID = t.ID
    WHERE t.StatusID<4
END
```

Comment: The whole idea is that I have a person (table1) who is enrolled in a class and a class have a status (Status table) and what I want is to prevent insertion into column TimeStamp when the StatusId < 4,  because when person have status from 4-5 a person is enrolled and is given a TimeStamp.  I hope it's a little clearer now.

Comment: Well if you want to prevent insertion of whole row then you should use code provided in answer by @Charlieface, if you want to just insert row without TimeStamp then code above does the work. I am not sure what you are aiming for as you said one thing in question and another in this comment.

Comment: _person (table1) ... enrolled in a class..._ Do you see how using actual, useful names makes your problem more clear and easier to understand and discuss? Generic names like "table1" just make things more difficult.

Comment: Yes I see know that I wasn't expressing my self very clearly, basically I want when StatusId < 4 and TimeStamp  =  NOT NULL prevent insert  and update and when  is StatusId > 4 update TimeStamp.